# How to translate Query to laravel Query Builder Union

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a query and the result like this

```
select "URL Listed" as _url, count(url) as total from listings where url != "0" group by 1 union all select "URL Not Listed" as _url, count(url) as total from listings where url = "0" group by 1
```

and result like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGCbB.png)
. Now i want to convert it to laravel. Maybe need some sugesstion may need it. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
$urls_details = DB::select("select 'URL Listed' as _url, count(url) as total from listings where url != '0' group by 1 union all select 'URL Not Listed' as _url, count(url) as total from listings where url = '0' group by 1");
```